# The line number on the SQL Editor in DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

How to toggle the line number on the SQL Editor in *DBeaver*?

I can't find this option in *Window / Preferences / General / Editors / SQL Editor*.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It is under *Window / Preferences / Editors / Text Editors*:

[image]

In older versions it was under *Window / Preferences / General / Editors / Text Editors*.

But as @simhumileco pointed out, there is a shortcut in the context menu when you right-click the left gutter of the editor.

Answer (score 37):

I found it:

**Right click** on **left column** of **SQL Editor** and click **Show / Hide Line Numbers** from **context menu**.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
Then, select the checkbox "Show Line Numbers"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In version *21.0.4.202105021514* it looks like this:

```
Windows > Preferences > Editors > Text Editors > Show line numbers
```

Comment: please improve your answer with an explanation

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the below steps:

```
Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Show line numbers
```

Comment: Downvote, this repeats the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, none of this answers work for me, so I decide to expose my answer.

**Environment**

```bash
DBeaver: Version 23.2.0.202309041200
Mac M1 Pro
```

**Steps**

```
Select the Script \
Right click on the UI very close to the beginning of the line \
Left clik on "Show Line Numbers" button
```

**Before solution**

[image: beaver-non-line-numbers]

**After solution**

[image: beaver-linu-numbers]